# Аналог JetBrains dotTrace Performance

Tags: c#, оптимизация, opensource, jetbrains

Не подскажите бесплатный аналог сабжа? Есть ли он вообще в природе?

Comment: Сейчас же такие скидки :) Сам не упустил шанс

Comment: Видел. Но для единовременного использования в курсовой платить 50$ нет желания :)

Comment: Дак есть же classroom бесплатный

Comment: Пробовал получить Classroom на ReSharper - отказали, т.к. лицензия только для преподавания, как я понял. Да, при попытке с dotTrace все то же.

Comment: Вариант "скачать с торрента" не рассматриваете? Тем более для разового использования...

Comment: А вообще 10 дней триала - должно хватить с головой

Comment: нет не рассматривается. да и нет там dotTrce под 11ую студию :)

Comment: для моих целей хватит 10дневного триала, на самом деле. Но вопрос все равно в силе.

Comment: ПОД студию он и не нужен - он вполне справляется с своими задачами в виде самостоятельного отдельного приложения (не знаю только насчет поддержки 4.5 фреймворка)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на правила лицензирования JetBrains для студентов:
https://www.jetbrains.com/student/

Также можете написать им в тех. поддержку, в т.ч. на русском языке.

Answer (score 0):

Аналог есть – ANTS Performance Profiler. Бесплатного нет, был бы бесплатный аналог, dotTrace бы не было. С большинством задач профилирования справляется и Visual Studio.